# Make a request on object load with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, rest

So I've had this problem for a while and still haven't found a solution after a lot of searching.
For some reason I can't get $("#id").load(function [...]); to work.

I have the following code

```
<button id="b1">Asd</button>
<textarea id="b1_res" rows="10" cols="180"></textarea>

<script>
    $("#b1_res").load(function(event) {
        alert("Dang, I got called...");
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "rest/noticias/todas",
            success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
                $("#b1_res").val(JSON.stringify(data))
            },
            error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#b1_res").val("ERROR: " + response.responseText + " / " + errorThrown)
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

It works when I use $("#b1").click( [...] ); even from external JS script.
Everywhere I search people don't seem to have this problem at all. When someone asks about this they just have the syntax wrong or something like that, which I think is not my case.
I'm obviously making some silly newbie mistake but I can't put my fingers around it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you need any more information just let me know and I'll update the question.

**EDIT**
I got it to work with kind of a workaround. This is how I did it:

```
<script>
    function populate() {
        alert("Dang, I got called...");
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "rest/noticias/todas",
            success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
                $("#b2_res").val(JSON.stringify(data))
            },
            error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#b2_res").val("ERROR: " + response.responseText + " / " + errorThrown)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<textarea id="b2_res" rows="10" cols="180"></textarea>
<script>populate();</script>
```

Not exactly what I was looking for though, so if anyone has any more input it would still be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the _actual_ code, or is the script element in reality placed somewhere else - like in the head of the document, before the element with the ID `b1_res` even exists …? Have you tried simply warring this in document ready, and see if that gives a different result?

Comment: That is the actual code I'm trying right now, as to make sure the script isn't loaded before the textarea.  Warring it in a $(document).ready(function() {}); didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have to use load method for load content from ajax in textarea field.

Yes, if in your document if have multiple textarea field and load this text area dynamically then only you need to use load() method.

In case of dynamically generated texarea field you can not use same value in id attribute. other wise jQuery find only first texterea element from document.

If your ajax content loaded based on id then you have to set some attribute dynamically and pass it in ajax request.

Your code should be something like this has dynamic textarea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ajax-content").each(function(){
    $this=$(this); // jquery dom object pointer
    $this.load(function(){
      loadTextFromAjax($this);
    })
  })
});

function loadTextFromAjax(textObj){
  var data_id= textObj.attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "rest/noticias/todas",
            data: {id: data_id},
            success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
                textObj.val(JSON.stringify(data))
            },
            error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                textObj.val("ERROR: " + response.responseText + " / " + errorThrown)
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">Asd</button>
<textarea data-id="b1" class="ajax-content" rows="10" cols="180"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take this into consideration going further! I don't have dynamically generated textareas though so it doesn't exactly apply to this particular case.